# How to retrieve derived classes as is from a Map?

Tags: scala, databricks

I have to retrieve Derived class objects stored in a Map given the respective class name as key.

As show below

```
trait Caluclator
class PreScoreCalculator(data:Seq[Int]) extends Caluclator
class BenchMarkCalculator(data:Seq[Int]) extends Caluclator


val calculatorsLookUp:Map[String, Calculator]  = Map[String, Calculator](
            "PreScore" -> new PreScoreCalculator,
             "BenchMark" -> new BenchMarkCalculator
            )
```

Given key name i need to get respective object/instance from Map

```
def getCalculatorByOperationName(operation:String) : Option[ Calculator]  = {
       calculatorsLookUp.get(operation)
    }
```

I am calling as below

```
   val calcName = "PreScore"

   val opt = getCalculatorByOperationName(calcName) 

   if(opt.isInstanceOf[PreScoreCalculator] )   /// this is coming as false
      calculationController.calculate(opt)     // this is not being executed.
```

Expect : 
   Execute calculationController.calculate(opt)

Error : 
    Above if condition is false hence not getting executed.

So how to handle this problem?

How to handle below i.e. default constructor objects ?

```
class PreScoreCalculator(data:Seq[Int]) extends Caluclator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `isInstanceOf` & `asInstanceOf` manually, because that is basically throwing the compiler away.
You should use **pattern matching** instead:

```
opt match {
   case Some(c: PreScoreCalculator) => calculationController.calculate(c)
   ... // Other calculators.
   case None => println("Calculator not found.")
}
```

*Note: This is basically the same Ichoran and I already said in gitter, I am just leaving this here for the record*.

Comment: Miguel Mejia Suarez Thank you so much for more clarity , if my PreScoreCalculator takes a constructor i.e. PreScoreCalculator(data:Seq[Int]) how can handle it , in the above scenario ?

Comment: @Miguel Mejia Suarez Can you please recommand good book for learning scala application design and best practices ?

Comment: @Shyam Can you elaborate that please? Do you need to extract that `Seq` too? PS: Can you modify the code of the Calculators, or those are out of you control?

Comment: @Shyam Technically speaking, SO is not a place to ask for books / courses recommendations... but, since it is a comment and not a question itself, I guess is not too bad. Of course everyone will think different, but I really liked **"Programming in Scala"** _(Book)_ & **"Functional Programming in Scala"** _(Coursera Specialization)_ for starting. And after a while _(most people recommend one year of experience)_ start learning about FP **"Scala with Cats"** is great to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You have a small bug:

`opt` is of type `Option[Calculator]`

In Scala a nice way to handle that is pattern matching:

```
opt match {
    case Some(calculator: PreScoreCalculator) =>
      calculationController.calculate(calculator)
    case _ => // nothing to do
  }
```

Or do it in a more declarative way:

```
  opt.filter(_.isInstanceOf[PreScoreCalculator])
      .foreach(calculationController.calculate)
```

However the use of `instanceOf` is a bit of an anti pattern.

As a tip:

Use `println(opt.getClass)` > then you see the class.

Comment: thank you for prompt reply , sorry this execute all the time even if the key is not PreScore. And  println(opt.getClass)  gives "class scala.Some"

Comment: you are right sorry - I fixed my answer and tested now both cases;)

Comment: thank you so much , why are using foreach here ? What am I iterating here ?

Comment: `opt` is of type `Option[Calculator]`. If you want do something with it you have to unwrap it, to use it > `foreach` does that - check the API of `Option`.

Comment: Thank you for clarity , if my PreScoreCalculator takes a constructor i.e. PreScoreCalculator(data:Seq[Int]) how can handle it , in the above scenario ?

Comment: if `calculate` takes a `Calculator` you handle it like above - otherwise you have to adjust your question and add the `calculate` function for clarity.

Comment: okey let me put it in different way ?  how to put this  "class PreScoreCalculator(data:Seq[Int]) extends Caluclator " in Map ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is on

```
val opt = getCalculatorByOperationName(calcName)
```

because it will return `Option[Calculator]` not `Calculator`. Now it will look like this..

```
if(opt.map(_.isInstanceOf[PreScoreCalculator]).getOrElse(false))
  calculationController.calculate(opt.get)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you , may i know why are you using .map here ? if it is not .isInstanceOf[PreScoreCalculator] returns false if the key is not "PreScore" right ? why do we need .getOrElse(false) ???

Comment: Okay. First, result of the `opt ` is always `Option[Calculator]` and Scala’s Predef object offers an implicit conversion that lets you write key -> value as an alternate syntax for the pair (key, value). In case the result is None then it will go to  `.getOrElse(false) ` so it is safe.

Comment: Can you please help me what went wrong here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080797/unable-to-write-parquet-file-due-error-sparkexception-job-aborted-fileforma